# FOR loop in R; not getting what I want

Tags: r, for-loop

Just a general question:

When I run:

```
ok<-NULL
for (i in 1:3) {
ok[i]=i^2
i=i+1
}
```

The loop works (as expected).

```
> ok
[1]  1  4  9
```

Now when I try to do something like:

```
ok<-NULL
for (i in 1:3) {
ok[i]=i^2
x[i]<-ok[i]+1
y[i]<-cbind(ok[i],x)
i=i+1
}
```

And I want:

```
y = 1
    2
    4
    5
    9
    10
```

Instead I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In y[i] <- rbind(ok[i], x) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In y[i] <- rbind(ok[i], x) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In y[i] <- rbind(ok[i], x) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In y[i] <- rbind(ok[i], x) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In y[i] <- rbind(ok[i], x) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest a read of the free PDF "The R Inferno" by Patrick Burns. http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on R basics before starting to program.

- You don't have to increment i in the loop (actually its quite confusing).
- You don't cbind or rbind vectors this is for data.frame columns and rows.

> ```
> y <- NULL
> for(i in 1:3){ ok <- i^2; x <- ok + 1; y <- c(y, ok, x) }
>
> or:
> as.vector(sapply(1:3, function(i){ ok <- i^2; x <- ok + 1; c(ok, x) }))
> ```

Comment: This was just a stupid made up example. But thanks, I figured out my mistake through your code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With this command `y[i]<-cbind(ok[i],x)` you attempt to replace one element in the vector with several. This causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to to get `1:3` squared, you would use:

```
ok <- (1:3)^2
ok
# [1] 1 4 9
```

If you want to get `1:3` squared, along with the numbers right after them, you might try:

```
as.vector(rbind(ok, ok+1))
[1]  1  2  4  5  9 10
```

`for` loops in R are often the wrong solution to your problem.